# Бинарные файлы и двусвязный список

Tags: c, файлы, двусвязный-список

Есть: 2 двусвязных списка.
Каждый элемент(Element) которого хранит какую-то информацию, и свой, вложенный двусвязный список(ItemLocal)
Т.е :

```
 struct Element 
{
char * name;
ItemLocal * Head;
ItemLocal * Tail;

Element * next;
Element * prev;

};

struct ItemLocal
{
char *field1;
char *field2;
..
ItemLocal * next;
ItemLocal* prev;
};
```

Ну и главная структура:

```
 struct CityList
 {
 Element * Head;
 Element * Tail;
 };
```

Но она мало интересна.
Сохранение:

```
  while (current)
  {
     fwrite(current, sizeof(Element), 1, lp);
     fwrite("\r\n", sizeof(char), 1, lp);
     current = current->next;
  }
```

Я так понимаю, что информация из указателей char *str, ItemLocal * head и тд не записывается файл?
Как быть? Как правильно записать, а потом считывать информацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце - записывать только строку, на которую указывает `name`. Можно записывать сначала ее длину, потом строку - **бинарно**, типа

```
int len = strlen(name)+1;
fwrite(&len,sizeof(len),1,file);
fwrite(name,len,1,file);
```

Читать - считываете строку, а указатели на предыдущий/следующий расставляете вручную - потому что записывать значения указателей, а тем более их читать - совершенно бессмысленно. Читать опять же, примерно так же:

```
int len;
fread(&len,sizeof(len),1,file);
current->name = malloc(len);
fread(name,len,1,file);
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что по сути дела мне придется с самого нуля формировать новый список, а в файл я только записываю значения полей??
Т.е. записываю Name, потом записываю поля вложенного списка.

Как при считывании отделять первый список от второго?
Берем пример, записываем инфу в файл. Файл получился такой:
FirstyName
field1
field2
field1
field2
SecondName
field1
field2
Как это считывать? Т.е вопрос такой: как контролировать количество элементов во втором списке? Оно ведь может быть разным

Comment: Да, нужно самостоятельно связи строить. Просто так прочесть не получится - если работаете с указателями. Ну, а с количеством - например, самым первым записать число последующих записей. Или маркер - если запись с отрицательным (или, скажем, нулевым) значением длины - значит, список закончился. Словом, разработайте свой формат файла - что и за чем должно идти - и работайте в соответствии с этой спецификацией...

Comment: >>Словом, разработайте свой формат файла
К сожалению с подобным не сталкивался. Или под этим подразумевается просто создание файла со своим расширением и запись туда в соответствии с правилам?

Остальное понял, спасибо Вам.

Comment: Ну просто какую-то схему - что за чем в файле должно идти.

Comment: @TorSen, вам по сути нужен **бинарный протокол**, вот и займитесь его воплощением